# no response after hibernate/suspend

Tags: suspend, amd-graphics, hibernate, amd-processor, msi

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on an MSI modern 14 B5M.

After I suspend or hibernate the notebook all the icons are replaced by this white rectangles and clicking on them doesn't work. In the login screen, when I type the password after I press enter nothing happens.

I've made this tries with no results:

- upgraded swap size to 11GB
- replaced the login manager with another one
- disabled automatic turn off of the ssd
- tried restarting using quick command prompt(Alt + F2)

I'm experiencing this problem with another distros (Ubuntu 22.10, Ubuntu 23.04, Linux Mint, etc) as well

###### Video Card

```
lspci | grep VGA 03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lucienne (rev c2)
```

###### Kernel Version

```
5.19.0-41-generic
```

###### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: The fact many different OS have the same issue points to hardware. You are asking a video question but there is no mention of a graphics card or driver or what kernel you are using. Please edit the question and ad this info. Not in the comments. Also what is the version of Ubuntu you are running right now, just to be clear.

Comment: ok, I've added this informations. I'm not very practiced, I hope I did everything right

Comment: Is there an earlier version of Ubuntu or Mint that works fine? Does it act the same way when you're hibernating a Live USB instead of the installed OS?

Comment: @David It could be hardware, but keep in mind that Mint is related to Ubuntu, and they have a lot of software in common; also Ubuntu 22.10 and 23.04 are sequential releases, so it could be a recent issue that has not been reported or fixed, yet.